# Average transactions per active week Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this

```
user_id customer_id transaction_amount  transaction_type    transaction_date
0       0             10000               debit               2020-09-08
1       1             20000               debit               2020-09-08
```

Now I want to calculate the average amount of transactions of each user in the weeks. So far I have achieved

```py
df.groupby(['user_id', 'transaction_date']).mean()
```

Which gives me the output in the following format

```
                                                       transaction_amount
user_id                              transaction_date   
1                                       2021-03-08      36114.913043
                                        2021-03-09      13425.000000
                                        2021-03-23      14915.200000
                                        2021-03-24      9762.000000

2                                       2021-03-08      1234114.913043
                                        2021-02-08      1354325.000000
                                        2021-12-23      141241915.200000
                                        2021-5-21       9735162.000000
```

How can I get it in the format of

```
user_id | customer_id | average_transactions_per_week 
_______________________________________________________
1          1                5 # 5 transactions in 1 week
2          2                8 # 8 transactions in 1 week
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit larger input example? And the **matching** expected output

Comment: Is customer_id and user_id the same?

Comment: @43zombiegit no they can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you shouldn't use `sum` but `count`. Also, to group by week, you need to compute a grouper, here we can use a period:

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'customer_id', pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date']).dt.to_period('W')]).agg(transactions_per_week=('user_id', 'count'))
```

Output:

```
                                           transactions_per_week
user_id customer_id transaction_date                            
0       0           2020-09-07/2020-09-13                      1
1       1           2020-09-07/2020-09-13                      1
```

Now to get the average number of transactions, you need a second `groupby`:

```
(df
 .groupby(['user_id', 'customer_id', pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date']).dt.to_period('W')])
 .agg(average_transactions_per_week=('user_id', 'count'))
 .groupby(['user_id', 'customer_id']).mean()
 )
```

Output:

```
                     average_transactions_per_week
user_id customer_id                               
0       0                                      1.0
1       1                                      1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date']).dt.week
df.groupby(['user_id', 'customer_id', 'transaction_date', 'week']).mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'user_id': [0, 1], 'customer_id': [0, 1], 'transaction_amount': [10000, 20000], 'transaction_type': ['debit', 'debit'], 'transaction_date': ['2020-09-08', '2020-09-08']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date'])
avgdf = df.groupby(['transaction_date','user_id'], as_index= False).size().rename(columns={'size': 'avg_trans_amount'})
df = df.merge(avgdf, on = ['transaction_date','user_id'])
print(df)
```